Convert local image to Base64 in react native But can't find image path
I want to convert local image to Base64 in react native But can't find image path. My image is stored in src/assets/images/myImage.png. What do i do to get the exact image path?
I have tried Image.resolveAssetSource() and many other thing but unable to find the solution.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The query is self explanatory

Hello @SameedSharif, welcome to StackOverflow although your problems speaks for itself, it is never a bad idea to add your code to the question because it gives us a more in depth view.
